# is there a book for training fundamental properties of functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I study mathematics alone and I need help.

I'm studying H. Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* and I encountered with some properties of functions.

in particular, I can't deal with some parts of the chapter of cardinality even though I solved all problems before the chapter.

As I guessed, I'm weak for some properties of functions, e.g. decision of injectivity and surjectivity(and bijectivity);  their implications for the case of composite functions; and decision of existence of a function from its form.

I want to train this abilities for the future.

some people suggested me the books about undergraduate analysis, category theory, or undergraduate algebra.

but they are huge fields so I want to train this properties only for now.

is there a book for training this properties?

Comment: How to Prove it:  A Structured Approach - by Velleman, covers what you need at the apropriate level of rigor.

Comment: thank you for recommendation. can I ask you one more thing about studying math? can you suggest a book for reviewing precalculus? because many years passed after I studied first semester calculus course, so I lost many feelings on solving simple questions.

Comment: It's been very long since I've studied Precal, I can't recall any relevent textbooks. I believe, Khan Academy is a good resource for pretty much any topic in PreCal. For anything in Calculus ( semesters 1-3) MitOpen Courseware is a good resource.